# TypeORM fails to connect without any error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to get started with TypeORM, but cannot get createConnection to work. I run the default `tpyeorm init` server file, but there is not error or logging shown, nor is the postgres DB updated.

index.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import {createConnection, ConnectionOptions} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "./entity/User";
import * as ormconfig from '../ormconfig.json';

console.log("is the file called correctly?");

createConnection(ormconfig as ConnectionOptions).then(async connection => {//ive also tried removing this 'async' keyword, but that doesnt help

    console.log("Inserting a new user into the database...");
    const user = new User();
    user.firstName = "Timber";
    user.lastName = "Saw";
    user.age = 25;
    await connection.manager.save(user);
    console.log("Saved a new user with id: " + user.id);

    console.log("Loading users from the database...");
    const users = await connection.manager.find(User);
    console.log("Loaded users: ", users);

    console.log("Here you can setup and run express/koa/any other framework.");

}).catch(error => console.log(error));

console.log('is this code reached?')
```

ormconfig.json (note: I changed the postgres password to 'root')

```
{
   "type": "postgres",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 5432,
   "username": "postgres",
   "password": "root",
   "database": "mhfit",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": true,
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
}
```

running start gives the following output:

```
> mhfit-server@0.0.1 start /home/james/Documents/mhfit/mhfit-server
> ts-node src/index.ts

is the file called correctly?
is this code reached?
```

Note that none of the other logging statements are hit. Why is that? Neither are errors shown.

postgres databases on my local machine:

```
User$ sudo -i -u postgres
'postgres@user:~$ psql
postgres=# \list
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 mhfit     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

The default `User` table is not created after trying to start the server

```
postgres-# \c mhfit
You are now connected to database "mhfit" as user "postgres".
mhfit-# \dt
Did not find any relations.
```

`Update`

I followed and downloaded the code from [this tutorial](https://dev.to/bnevilleoneill/how-to-build-a-graphql-api-with-typegraphql-and-typeorm-58fb), and magically it worked. But unfortunately my old project still failed...

Eventually I tried messing with my models, and discovered that the failure was due to TypeORM not liking how I setup some of my models. I have a model, `A` that can have two arrays of model `B` (Bs that exist before event A, and Bs that exist after event A).

In TypeORM I had set this up to be 2 OneToMany relationships on A, and 2 ManyToOne relatonships on the B class. Something about this crashed TypeORM though. What is the correct way to do this instead?

A:

```
...
@OneToMany(type => B, preB => preB.preA)
preBs: B[];
@OneToMany(type => B, postB => postB.postA)
postEmotions: B[];
```

B:

```
...
@ManyToOne(type => A, preA => preA.preBs)
preA: A;
@ManyToOne(type => A, postA => postA.postBs)
postA: A;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the update I say that it failed to start due to an Entity setup issue. Entity `A` can have many `B`s, both before and after an event. I ended up getting it working by setting up the Entities as so:

```
//added this class just for fun
@InterfaceType()//TypeGraphQL stuff
export abstract class ParentEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Field(type => ID)//TypeGraphQL stuff
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() public id: number;

    @Field()
    @CreateDateColumn() public createdAt: Date;

    @Field()
    @UpdateDateColumn() public updatedAt: Date;
}


@InterfaceType({ implements: ParentEntity }) //TypeGraphQL stuff
export abstract class B extends ParentEntity { //Notice this is an abstract class now
    @Field()//TypeGraphQL stuff
    @Column({
        type: "varchar",
        length: 100,
        nullable: true
    })
    myField: string;
}

@Entity()
@ObjectType({ implements: B })//TypeGraphQL stuff
export class PostB extends B {
    @ManyToOne(type => A, postB => postB.A)
    myA: A;
}


@Entity()
@ObjectType({ implements: B })
export class PreB extends B {
    @ManyToOne(type => A, PreB => PreB.A)
    myA: A;
}


@Entity()
@ObjectType({ implements: ParentEntity })
export class A extends ParentEntity {
    @OneToMany(type => PreB, bPre => bPre.myA)
    preBs: PreB[];
    @OneToMany(type => PostB, bPost => bPost.myA)
    postBs: PostB[];
}
```

I also had to update my TypeORM package...

Edit: Duplicating your entities causes double the work when creating resolvers, seeders, and when querying on the front end. An easier way is to add a 'Type' enum field/column on the entity.